# Multiple threads executing code IF they are the same type

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Basically I have two classes that implement runnable, with n number of instantiations of these two classes, and I want them to be able to access a resource if they are the same type of class that is currently within the critical section. I also want to achieve fairness between the different class types.

Pseudocode:

```
if object is currentType, allow access to critical section
else, wait
```

What is the best way to achieve this? It's very similar to `ReentractReadWriteLock` where any amount of readers are allowed, but a writer is mutually exclusive. I need any amount of object of `Class1` allowed and any amount of `Class2` allowed but not both types at the same time.

Comment: Threads don't have types.

Comment: @SLaks OP *possibly* means `Class1 extends Thread` and `Class2 extends Thread`. Instances of these classes will have different types.

Comment: How do you see switching the semaphore from `Class1` to `Class2` and vice versa? What is your definition of "*fairness*"?

Comment: That's what I'm having trouble with. It seems as though Semaphores are traditionally used to limit the number of threads executing. I want the synchronization primitive (lock/semaphore/whatever) to limit the type of runnable executing, while keeping it fair between the two types.

Fairness I guess could be time based? Overall goal is that statistically the two types of runnable objects get the same amount of time within the critical section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a synchronization class that does what you want, but it sounds like a generalization of a Reader/Writer lock.  A reader/writer lock allows any number of "readers" to acquire the lock at the same time, *OR* it allows one "writer" to acquire the lock, but it never allows a "reader" and a "writer" to hold it at the same time.

What you want is, any number of "A" at the same time OR any number of "B" OR any number of "C" OR ...

I would read about how reader/writer locks work, and think about how to generalize the algorithm to meet your needs.

Pay special attention to how reader/writer locks handle the "fairness" problem.  What happens if there is *always* at least one A that wants the lock.  Once an A gets it, how will a B or a C ever get a chance?

Comment: This is the direction I'm going. In fact, before reading your suggestion I came up with a solution based off this idea. Will update once I have it implemented.

Comment: Since I took a different approach to the problem, I'm going to go ahead and accept this as the answer to my question. 

This answer reflects my initial design of restricting different "types" of threads reading a resource (multiple threads of the same time can read at the same time), and complete mutual exclusion of all threads writing to the resource.

Comment: I believe this is achievable via the Java read/write lock where if a thread is attempting to acquire a read lock, its type must be checked to see if it is the current type of thread allowed.

If it is, it is granted a read lock, if it's not, it will attempt to acquire the write lock. From my limited understanding of Java read/write locks, a writelock disallows any more granting of readlocks and waits until all threads with read locks are finished to write. In my case the write would write its thread type to the resource so that this different thread type could read the resource next.

Answer (score 0):

So every instance constitutes an individual thread running therefore if there are N instances there will be N threads running where K instances of Class1 and L instances of Class2.  And you only want to allow all instances (and by that extension all threads) of an individual type.  Either K instances of Class1 or L instances of Class2 into the critical section.

If all of this is true then you wouldn't write that ever allowed multiple threads into a critical section.  If any thread, regardless of Class type, could modify that object it doesn't matter the Class type because a modification is a modification and the results will be unpredictable allowing multiple threads to modify a critical section at the same time.  And if all of those instances were only reading a shared variable then there would be no need for a critical section.

Bottom line what you are asking for doesn't make any sense to solve.

Comment: No thread is modifying anything. The non-technical requirements require mutual exclusion of the two types.

Comment: Well you don't need a critical section then.  Critical sections are only required for when a modification is occurring to a shared object.  I think you can accomplish some separation between these two collections of threads with a different architecture, but the details of what you are really trying to do haven't been included so there are limits on what we can recommend.